# Sort both elements of a tuple, ignoring case, within a list, so that the keys of a dictionary line up correctly

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, equality

I am iterating two instances of the same class in order to check for equality. These two instances of this class are created by different means: one from a pickle, and the other from a json document.

I am iterating through the properties of these objects, to check for equality, however, the keys in the dictionaries do not always line up, so they can not be properly compared. So I tried sorting these tuples, but I cannot get the same key from both of these objects at all times because of case sensitivity.

One attempt gives me the left side sorted:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    for (self_key, other_key) in sorted(
         zip(self.__dict__, other.__dict__),
         key=lambda element: (element[0].lower(), element[1].lower())):            
            print self_key, " ", other_key
      ....
```

which outputs

```
alpha   VAR_THRESH
chunksize   VAR_MAXITER
decay   decay
....
```

And if I explicitly make only the right side `lower()` I get the opposite: e.g.

```
  ....
   key=lambda element: (element[0], element[1].lower())):
  ....
```

The left side is not sorted by lower.

```
VAR_MAXITER   alpha
VAR_THRESH   chunksize
alpha   VAR_THRESH
chunksize   VAR_MAXITER
decay   decay
```

If I leave out the `.lower()` on both of the elements, I get the second example.

How can I ensure that the correct keys always line up? Or in other words, how can I sort by both values in the tuples, ignoring case, so that they always line up?

Comment: Order is irrelevant, if the dicts have the same objects they will compare equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip()` will give you the corresponding elements in each iterable that you give it.  Sorting what `zip()` returns will not help you.  You need to sort the keys before you pass them to `zip()`.  That really isn't what you want, though.  Just do this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.__dict__.viewkeys() != other_keys.__dict__.viewkeys(): # .keys() in Python 3
        return False
    return all(other.__dict__[key] == self.__dict__[key] for key in self.__dict__)
```

The easy way would be this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

but the first you can more easily change to define what counts as equivalent.

The following (proposed by Padraic Cunningham) is closer to what you want:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return all(
        sorted(v) == sorted(self.__dict__[key])
            if isinstance(v, np.array)
        else self.__dict__[key] == v
        for key, v in other.__dict__.iteritems()
    )
```

That is a shortcut for this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    for key, v in other.__dict__.iteritems(): # .items() in Python 3
        if isinstance(v, np.array) and sorted(v) != sorted(self.__dict__[key]):
                return False
        elif self.__dict__[key] != v:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I need to iterate through the keys of the dict because one of the values is an np array. Your answer before the edit helped me arrive at the correct answer though, if you revert it back, I will accept.

Comment: @nook: Okay; I rolled back.

Comment: `if d2.keys() != d1.keys()` is sufficient, or `if d2.viewkeys() != d1,viewkeys()` for python2, no need to make sets

Comment: You would use viewkeys in this case as I think from the print statement, the OP is using python2, it should be  faster than comparing lists.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Okay; I have changed it to use `.viewkeys()` with a comment about `.keys()`.  Anything else?  I'll be here for a little while longer ;)

Comment: Well since you asked `all(sorted(v) == sorted(self.__dict__[key]) if isinstance(v, np.array) else self.__dict__[key] == v  for key, v in other.__dict__.iteritems())`  ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `Traceback (most recent call last): BrainOverload`  I'll see if I can manage to make it semi-readable in an actual function.  I'd make that a separate solution, though.

Comment: @zondo, yep, hard to do in a comment though!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Okay; I've done my best at making it readable.  Do you think it looks all right?

Comment: I just removed the nesting, bar that it look fine

Answer (score -1):

Dictionaries are inherently unordered. Coercing the keys into some ordering that fits your particular definition is certainly possible, but also entirely unnecessary. You could instead try something like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):

  # first, check to make sure that the two sets of keys are identical
  if self.__dict__.keys() != other.__dict__.keys():
    return False

  # now that we know the dictionaries have identical key sets, check
  # for equality of values.
  for key in self.__dict__.keys():
    if self.__dict__[key] != other.__dict__[key]:
      return False

  # if everything worked, then the dictionaries are identical!
  return True
```